# ERROR kuhl_sekurlsa_acquireLSA from customized mimikatz

Tags: windows, windows-10, c++, privileged-account, mimikatz

Tried to call `sekurlsa::logonpasswords` function from mimikatz main source, but I get `ERROR hl_aaaurlsa_acquireLSA ; Logon list`

The program is executed with Administrator cred and I'm sure there's no problem with the environment because the original mimikatz source runs successfully if I use the two lines of main(call to privilege and sekurlsa) I use for the customized mimikatz. main:

```
int wmain(int argc, wchar_t * argv[])
{
    kuhl_privilege.commands[0].pCommand(0, NULL); // privlege::debug
    kuhl_sekurlsa.commands[7].pCommand(0, NULL); // sekurlsa::logonpasswords

    return 0;
}
```